# Closing React native Modal is not working

Tags: react-native, simplemodal

I want to have a Modal in React native like below, where the Modal should close onPress to the 'close' text. [demo picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmww2.png)

The ModalProps is coming from the previous component as true. OnPress to 'close' I want the 'visible' to be false and the Modal to be closed. My OS is Android. The Code is below:

```js
type ModalProps = {
    visible: boolean  // visible = true here from the previous screen
}


const closeModal = ():void => {
    // code to make the visible false
}

function myModal ({visible}: ModalProps) {
    return (
        <Modal visible={visible}>
            <View>
                <Text> this is my Modal</Text> 
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text onPress={() => this.closeModal()}>Dismiss</Text>
            </View>
        </Modal>
    );
}

export default myModal;
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parent component should have a state like `modalVisible` to handle the modal visibility.
So your parent component should pass the function prop like `onPressClose`

**ParentComponent**:

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import Modal from 'react-native-modal';

function ParentComponent() {

  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true); // Starts with what visibility you want.

  return (
    <MyModal visible={visible} onPressClose={() => setVisible(false)} />
   );
}
```

**ModalComponent:**

```js
// imports...

function MyModal ({visible, onPressClose}){
  return (
    <Modal visible={visible}>
      <View>
         <Text> this is my Modal</Text> 
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text onPress={onPressClose}> Dismiss </Text>
      </View>
    </Modal>

   );
  }
```